# start my app from browser works only in chrome

Tags: android, browser, launching-application

I've written an app which is to be started from a browser via html link (company internal net, NOT internet). I've defined an intent-filter with an own URL scheme in AndroidManifest.xml and it works fine, but only for Google Chrome. 
All other Browsers try to load a website, which does not exist. 
My Device: Nexus 10 with Android 4.2

Section in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
            <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="camerastarter" android:host="wrap" android:path="/" />
        </intent-filter>
```

HTML:

[a href="camerastarter://wrap/?param1=value1&param2=value2"]Start Camera[/a]

My employer wants a full screen Browser and Chrome has no full screen option.
Is there any chance to start the app from other browsers/WebView-using apps?

(Btw, the same problem appears with the zxing barcode scanner. Only Chrome can start it from a html link.)

I'm very grateful for any help....